# Is there a point playing Diablo III before the season starts?

Tags: diablo-iii

I plan to start a season char right away (on Friday) and right now I don't know if there's any benefit to playing my non season chars. I'm in Europe.

Comment: Well, the most important reason to ever play a video game is to have fun. You can try that I guess. If you're looking to play Season, and it hasn't started, then no, nothing you do now is going to effect than besides gaining meta-knowledge about anything that may have changed since you last played, if it's been a while.

Comment: Well all I ever did in D2 LoD was play ladder so now that we have ladders in D3 that's what I Will be doing :)

Comment: ...to have fun?  I dunno, why do you play games in the first place?

Comment: Also, double Gold and double Treasure Goblins is going on. Whenevery you find one, there are 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well if there is a point... That's entirely up to your personal view. You just have to know that Seasonal Characters are **cut off from normal characters**. This basically means: you don't have access to Gold and Items.

So basically if you want to gain an advantage through farming extra gold for your seasonal characters the answer would be: No, there is no point in playing your current characters. However you can still try to find out how to level extremely fast (so basically Practicing with your current characters) and of course you can also play for fun.

Also a thing to note: Seasonal characters become normal characters after a season has ended.

Answer (score 1):

Seasonal characters cannot benefit from gold, items, crafting or paragon levels from non-season characters. They function the same way as harcore characters in this way.

Farming on your non-season character won't give you a tangible advantage to the season- assuming that's what you mean by "a point".